# can ip packets be lost between two hosts on the same subnet?

Tags: networking, tcp

Can ip packets be lost between two hosts on the same subnet, or does a router need to be involved? And, I have the same question about packet reordering.

I should clarify that this is a subnet on a wired network in a data center with two web services communicating over http.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, packets can be lost in a wired network in a data center.

At my house some sources of packet loss include:

- The cat peed on the switch
- The rabbit chewed through the Ethernet wire
- The wife moved the cable because it was ugly
- The power went out
- I knocked the switch off the shelf

While all of those are possible at a professionally-run data center, they seem unlikely as causes of your packet loss. However, even data centers have problems:

- The switch gets flaky when it overheats
- The endpoint computers get flaky when they overheat
- The packet volume overwhelms the switch's fabric
- The packet volume overwhelms the endpoint computer
- Some 3rd-party computer poisons the ARP cache

If you are using TCP, then packet loss recovery almost certainly results in re-ordered packets.

```
Sender: Hey Bob, here's packet 78
Sender: Hey Bob, here's packet 79
Sender: Hey Bob, here's packet 80
Bob: Whoa, Sender, I'm missing 78!
Sender: Hey Bob, here's packet 78
Bob: Okay, I've got 78, 79, and 80.
Sender: Hey Bob, here's packet 81
```

You can see, the sender sent the packets 78, 79, 80, 78, and 81. To an outside observer, that might be perceived as out of order, since he sees the sequence 80, 78, 81.

Comment: those mostly seem unlikely. when you say "packet volume overwhelms the endpoint computer" do you mean that the data arrives faster than the host can process it (e.g. some receive buffer is full when new data arrives)?

Comment: Yes, the switch's buffers might be full, or the endpoint computer's buffers may be full. To measure the latter, try `ifconfig eth0 | grep dropped`.  P.s. you'll get better answers at the related site: http://serverfault.com

Answer (score 0):

Depends on what the underlying link-level protocol used on the network is.  The answer will be "yes" for most wireless protocols and "no" for some (but not all) wired protocols.

Comment: does what you say hold true for packet reordering as well as packet loss? And, what is the reason why packets can't be lost on the same subnet (i guess this is kind of like asking how packets get lost, which doesn't seem like it would happen if there's a known route)?